# Find Paragraph with BackgroundPatternColor but with any style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am searching through a Word (2016) document with a VBA function looking for paragraphs that have a background color of Yellow applied.  This works well if the style of the paragraph is `Normal`...

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Text = ""
End With

While Selection.Find.Execute
    ' do the thing
Wend
```

Once I run this, I can then open the Advanced Find dialog in Word and this is what shows:

[image: Search dialog showing VBA-set formatting]

There are some paragraphs with a yellow background pattern that are not `Style = "Normal"` and as it happens, I can use the Format -> Style dialog to remove the requirements that the Style is `Normal`...

[image: Remove the style requirement]
[image: Now searches all styles]

If I go back to VBA now, I can use `Selection.Find.Execute` and I can locate the paragraphs that were missed before.  Interrogating the `Selection.Find.Style` property reveals the value `Normal`, which is as before, except now it works.

There does not appear to be any way, in VBA, to remove the Style requirement?
**Does anyone know how to do this?**

I tried setting the `Style` value to:

- Nothing
- ""
- "(no style)"
- 9999999

None of these worked.  I also tried setting `Find.Format = False` but that didn't work either.  I think it's odd that the `Find.Style` property in VBA still shows `Normal` but if I set it to `Normal` the search fails to find the paragraph.

Open to any suggestions at this point.

Comment: All I can do is confirm what you report. To that I can add that recording a macro from the Find dialog box includes the line `Selection.Find.style = ActiveDocument.styles("")` but when I try to run this macro or use this approach I get the error 5941 "The requested member of the collection does not exist". Also, the recorded macro does not include the BackgroundColor setting, although the Find dialog box is using it.

Comment: One other observation: The Find dialog box does not support searching shading or borders (except when they're part of a style). That might being playing a role, here. Find+VBA are allowing something (to a certain extent) that's not "supported" - at least, not in the UI.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for confirming my observations. I really don’t have any way to proceed from here. I tried looking at the values in the Find object in Watch but it just crashes Word. This is probably an edge case nobody’s looked at before.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will help, but this simple macro finds all text with Tan shading, regardless of style. Maybe you can use this to find text with a specific background shading and then select the entire paragraph.

```
Sub FindTanShading()
   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
   With Selection.Find
     .Text = ""
     .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorTan
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

If you have found another solution in the meantime, please share it.

Comment: After some more testing, I found found that this macro works in some documents but not others. No idea why.

Comment: Thanks @YossiD but this question is 2.5 years old. We gave up on this a long time ago